# Quill Editor in Angular (editor.root.innerHTML)

Tags: html, css, angular, quill

I have a problem using the Quill Editor. I want to show the inserted content of the Quill editor in another HTML Tag.

I tried to use the following code:

```
configureQuill() {
const toolbarOptions = [
  ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
  [{ 'align': [] }],
  [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
  [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
  [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
  ['image', 'formula']
];
const options = {
  modules: {
      toolbar: toolbarOptions,
      formula : true,
      imageResize: {}
  },
  placeholder: 'Hier goes the content...',
  theme: 'snow'
};
this.q = new Quill('#editor2', options);
this.q.on('editor-change', (eventName, ...args) => {
  if (eventName === 'text-change') {
    this.contentHtml = this.q.root.innerHTML;
  }
});
}
```

And I am using the contentHTML variable to put the HTML content into a div Container:

```
<div [innerHTML]="contentHtml">
```

The content is shown but I think the css styles are not used for the content in the div container:

[image]

Everything works fine except the formula, the text-alignment and the text size.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding the following css-class to my div-container: ql-editor.

Furthermore I changed the way of pasting the HTML content as follows:

```
this.q.on('editor-change', (eventName, ...args) => {
  if (eventName === 'text-change') {
    const justHtmlContent = document.getElementById('contentHtml');
    this.contentHtml = this.q.root.innerHTML;
    justHtmlContent.innerHTML = this.contentHtml;
  }
});
```